# Determine if user is a domain administrator

Tags: google-oauth

I see in https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people#resource
that we get the domain name. But I don't see any indication of the user role. I would like to know if the user is a domain administrator so that I can give them more rights within our application.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/) to get that info. Note that you will need an OAuth token with admins rights to use this API.

Comment: So when the user signs up for my service, I would ask if they are signing up as the account admin, and if so I would include that scope, right?

Comment: Or you can always include the scope and then see if you're able to use the token to access the directory API. If yes then the guy is admin.